# Is there a game semantical countermodel to Markov's Principle?

Tags: logic, combinatorial-game-theory, constructive-mathematics

For specificity, let's fix Markov's Principle as
$$\forall P : \mathbb N \to 2. \neg(\forall n : \mathbb N. P(n) = 0) \to \exists m : \mathbb N. P(m) = 1.$$
I've seen an informal argument that this should be invalid for an interpretation of $P$ as ranging over choice sequences in an environment where the sequence is being chosen *maliciously*; framed game-semantically, Opponent could continually extend the sequence with $0$s to an arbitrary length, preventing verification of the $\exists$, but immediately insert a $1$ should Player try to refute the $\neg\forall$ premise. (Of course, this would hinge on Player not being able to subsequently go back and win by verifying the conclusion with the newly-inserted $1$, which does seem problematic since I guess it would suggest an additive interpretation of the $\to$ in the body?)

Is there some formal construction which captures this concept?

Comment: In which kind of logic are you? In classical logic the antecedent of the implication is logically equivalent to the consequent of the implication.

Comment: I don't really have a fixed logic in mind that I'd want a model of, as long as MP is refuted by an argument along the lines I gave.

Comment: I don't know game semantics well enough to give a complete answer. However, the reason you cannot 'go back and win' will likely be the same thing that prevents you from modelling $¬¬P → P$, which is classical. You cannot challenge the $¬¬P$, force the opponent to assert $P$ and then go back assert $P$ yourself. Once you challenge $¬¬P$ you must lose if the opponent is able to assert $P$. In this light, Markov's principle is just a more plausible instantiation of $P$.

Comment: The reason the principle is plausible is if we presume that the behavior of $P : ℕ → 2$ must be given up front. Then the opponent must choose behavior that allows them to justify the $¬∀$ assertion, and we will eventually find it by search. So, an essential feature of the anti-Markov game would be that the opponent doesn't need to decide what $P$ does at any $n$ until challenged. So, they can always answer $0$ in response to a search, and only have to choose $1$ if you've decided to play a game you will lose if they do so.